# Перестали запускаться некоторые приложения после изменения размера раздела

Tags: ubuntu, gparted, раздел

Расширил раздел / с ~30ГБ до ~120ГБ, используя gparted. После этого перестал запускаться sublime text, то есть начинается загрузка, но в какой-то момент просто останавливается. Пробовал переустанавливать, ничего не помогло. Установил Atom - не запускается. В чём может быть проблема и как её решить?

Comment: `fsck.ext4` прогонял?

Comment: Нет, с каким ключом стоит проверить?

Comment: `-f`, `-p`, `-v`.